# How to determine if an icon is on the Action Bar or Overflow Menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have arranged for several icons to display on the Action Bar if there is room via my layout file.  How can one programmatically determine if a specific icon is displayed on the Action Bar vs displayed on the Overflow menu?

My objective is to color/tint it differently depending on where it is displayed.

```
<item android:id="@+id/new_complex_section"
android:title="@string/complex_section"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_complex_section"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/new_design_i_section"
        android:title="@string/i_section"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_i_section" />
    <item android:id="@+id/new_design_t_section"
        android:title="@string/t_section"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_t_section" />
</menu>
```

Comment: BTW, I have seen in other threads that if you are using the ActionBarSherlock do...  However, I am not using the ActionBarSherlock.